# Add to specific point in json data hierarchy with d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm starting off with a simple flat json input containing 10 elements,  each of which has a number of attributes and is represented by a d3 node.

When the user clicks on a node, it returns a new json file containing 10 children relating to the specific node that was clicked on (I can't load all the parent/child hierarchy data upfront since in theory there could be a huge amount of it).

I'm confused as to the best way to inject the new json data into the variable containing the original - so far I pull the original data and store it in a variable called defaultData...

```
//load default data for first 10 nodes
d3.json("php/first10nodes.php", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  var defaultData = json;
  update();
});
```

Then when a node is clicked a new php script is run to return the relevant json file, but I can't find out how to sum the data together, and particularly don't know how to ensure that this second piece of data  is inserted underneath the appropriate entry in defaultData (as identified in this case by d.id)...

```
d3.json("php/getDetail.php?ID="+ d.id, function(error, json) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);          
        // something like this??! defaultData = defaultData + json;
        update();
    });
```

Hope that's clear - really appreciate any advice.  Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas from anyone at all??  Thanks

Comment: just to keep this one in synch - I got some feedback on the d3 google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/B_g3vY6czrM (the solution involved creating a placeholder for expected children in my original data load).